# MongoItemReader and ISODate handling

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-batch

I am using  **org.springframework.batch.item.data.MongoItemReader**
and while using

```
mongoItemReader.setQuery({'update_date' : {$gte : ISODate('2014-01-01T12:00:00.000Z')}});
```

I am getting exception like 
**com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException**:

so I changed my query to :

```
{'update_date' : {$gte : '2014-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'}}
```

now I am not getting this exception but getting readcount=0 which is not correct, because **{'update_date' : {$gte : ISODate('2014-01-01T12:00:00.000Z')} is giving me readcount=20**.

How to handle this?

Comment: You use `java.util.Date` types. Or at least anything that produces that object. That is what the driver expects in order to match anything stored as a BSON Date.

Comment: Do you mean instead of passing '2014-01-01T12:00:00.000Z' as string, I should pass java.util.Date object?

Comment: Yep. Which is exactly like what one of the many duplicate questions I am about to point you to will all say in their answers. `java.util.Date` is the expected type.

Comment: I tried that and it turns my query into {'update_date' : {$gte : Wed Jan 01 00:00:00 CST 2014}} which is still throwing json parse exception

Comment: mongoItemReader.setQuery() accepts string value only, even if I cast it, it will accept it as a string. Anyway if you dont know the answer you can just ignore the question and resume your work, but don't be rude on beginers because you have so many reputation points. thanks.